# Spring Boot Batch with JpaPagingItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am using JpaPagingItemReader with page size 40. but every batch execution i am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed

Below is code

```
@Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
        public ItemReader<QuoteOfferFulfillment> reader() {
            JpaPagingItemReader<QuoteOfferFulfillment> fullfillment = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
            try {
                String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM QUOTE_OFFER_FULFILLMENT QOF WHERE QOF.STATUS='"
                        + FULFILLMENT_READY + "'" + " OR QOF.STATUS='"
                        + FAILED + "'" + " AND RETRY_COUNT < 3";
                JpaNativeQueryProvider<QuoteOfferFulfillment> queryProvider = new JpaNativeQueryProvider<QuoteOfferFulfillment>();
                queryProvider.setSqlQuery(sqlQuery);
                queryProvider.setEntityClass(QuoteOfferFulfillment.class);
                queryProvider.afterPropertiesSet();
                fullfillment.setEntityManagerFactory(em.getEntityManagerFactory());
                //fullfillment.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
                fullfillment.setPageSize(40);
                fullfillment.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
                fullfillment.afterPropertiesSet();
                fullfillment.setSaveState(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("BatchConfiguration.reader() ==> error " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return fullfillment;
        }
```

Exception which i am facing:

```
[ERROR] org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step offersFulfillmentstep in job offersFulfillmentJob
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.checkOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.checkOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.getSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.getSession(TransactionImpl.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:45)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JpaPagingItemReader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[DEBUG] org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl - Mark transaction for rollback
[ERROR] org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Exception while closing step execution resources in step offersFulfillmentstep in job offersFulfillmentJob
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Error while closing item reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:136)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.close(CompositeItemStream.java:85)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.close(TaskletStep.java:305)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.checkOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.checkOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.close(EntityManagerImpl.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1564.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1171.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doClose(JpaPagingItemReader.java:236)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:133)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Observation: Every transaction is roll backing and it is processing success. Not sure what happening

I believe JpaPagingItemReader has a problem. It is causing entity close issue for every iteration then again processing success. Please let me know if any one face the same issue and any other alternative.

Comment: Is your class annotated with 
@ Configuration & @ EnableBatchProcessing?

Comment: Hi Reg, thanks for responding. yes I have declare has @configuration and @ Enablebatchprocessing. Addition of this job is running fine if I want to process record size is less than 20 every thing is working fine . If I try to do more than 20 records I am getting entity manager close exception using jpapagingitemreader

Comment: Which transaction manager have you configured Spring Batch to use? With JPA, you need to use the `JpaTransactionManager`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me @MahmoudBenHassine. but the problem didn't got resolved. please find the configurations below: Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;  Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return transactionManager;
    }

Comment: and the implementation is like below   JpaPagingItemReader<QuoteOfferFulfillment> fullfillment = new JpaPagingItemReader<>(); fullfillment.setEntityManagerFactory(jpaTransactionManager().getEntityManagerFactory());
            fullfillment.setPageSize(40);
            fullfillment.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
            fullfillment.afterPropertiesSet();
            fullfillment.setSaveState(true);

Comment: Just providing the `JpaTransactionManager` bean in your context is not enough. You need to provide a custom `BatchConfigurer`. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2724.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine: i have configured based on your suggestions. but i am getting different error now. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource must not be null
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.unwrapResourceIfNecessary(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:62)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:137)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doGetTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:331)

Comment: batch configuration file i have like Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();            transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() {
           return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(){
            @Override
            public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
                   return new JpaTransactionManager();
               }
           };
    }

Comment: did i done any wrong @MahmoudBenHassine. kindly help me to resolve the issue

Comment: This fix is available in version 4.1.0.M3. Are you using this version?

Comment: You batch configurer should not return a new JpaTransactionManager but the one declared as a bean: `public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() { return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(){ @Override public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() { return jpaTransactionManager() ; } `

Comment: I thought if i use below it will pick latest version, is it wrong <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine, the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource must not be null  problem got resolved. but if i update more than 30 records still i am getting old problem. is any other way to chat with you to resolve this issue. please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Sahre you project on github and I'll try to help.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine: As you suggested please find https://github.com/balu123456/offersEngine_Job.git  and mainly we are talking configuration, you can refer: https://github.com/balu123456/offersEngine_Job/tree/master/src/main/java/com/clearlane/offersengine_job/batchconfiguration. please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, Hope you are doing great, did you got a chance to look into the code ?? Please let me know your suggestions

Comment: I opened an issue on github: https://github.com/balu123456/offersEngine_Job/issues/1. Let's continue the discussion there.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine : still the same issue i am getting. i am trying different approach now using RepositoryItemReader. by giving methods its working awesome,  but i try to give native quires then i am facing the issue. the issue "is it works,but return Object[]" below is my repository method. i have post the code details in the github. please let me know your suggestions.